# Is IELTS/TOEFL/German language proficiency score required for German student visa for PhD?

Tags: germany, student-visa

I have received a PhD admission from the Max Planck Institute. I have been collaborating with researchers there for a year as a part of my Bachelor's thesis and before that, I was a research intern there. So, I did not need to submit any English language score for the admission process.

Will I be required one by the embassy for the visa? I saw this mentioned in some online sources. I am not sure how strong this requirement is. Can I get some form of waiver from MPI?

Comment: Have you contacted the IMPRS coordinator at your soon-to-be-host institute? He/she can likely answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually there are two options of getting a residence permit (later you will need to apply for it in Germany): either as student (§16 AufenhG) or as researcher/employee (§18 AufenthG or §19a AufenthG (Blue Card)).

Option 1: If you are going to get a scholarship and be a student, the important point here is whether the English or German language certificate is required for the enrolment into the university. It indeed could be that the university will ask you to provide English certificate, however, for PhD it could be rather relaxed and depends more on your professor; if he wants to take you, usually he will be able to manage it even without English certificate, if he really really wants do deal with it (which is often not the case).
If you are enrolled into the university, or get a brief that you will be enrolled, I would suggest that it should be enough for the embassy.

Option 2: You will be researcher/employee. Then embassy will be mainly interested in your contract and size of salary, I doubt the language certificate matters in this case.